# Error using Google Page Speed Api (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-pagespeed

I have trouble using Google page speed api Node client.
I always get the following error when I do `node index.js` in the command line:

```
/Volumes/folder/pagespeed/index.js:7
}).then(function(res) {
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/My iMac/ganlanyuan/pagespeed/index.js:7:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

index.js:

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var pagespeed = google.pagespeedonline('v2');

pagespeed.pagespeedapi.runpagespeed({
  'url': 'https://www.google.com/'
}).then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [googleapis docs](http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/22.2.0/pagespeedonline_.html#.pagespeedonline.pagespeedapi.runpagespeed__anchor), I don't see that API supports *Promise*, it works with *callback*, so you can't use `.then(...)`

```
var { google } = require('googleapis');
var pagespeed = google.pagespeedonline('v2');
pagespeed.pagespeedapi.runpagespeed({
    'url': 'https://www.google.com/'
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Samir Aleido,
I actually saw the example of promise using in the "Javascript" panel of [this page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v4/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed?apix=true), but maybe this is for browser use only.